# What happens when a creature wielding an Aegis of the Raven Queen gets breathed on by a fire-breathing dragon?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, dnd-adventurers-league, dragons, breath-weapon

I know this looks very similar to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/139259/what-happens-if-a-creature-draws-a-frostbrand-when-breathed-upon-by-a-fire-breat), but I asked it to indirectly solve what I'm about to ask now (a bad idea).

---

The *Aegis of the Raven Queen* (from the module ["CCC-BWM-03 A Tale of Two Towers"](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/253558/CCC--BWM--003-A-Tale-of-Two-Towers)) is a special shield, which does not exist in D&D 5e by default but does exist in Adventurers League play. It has the following passive property:

> While holding this shield, nonmagical flames are extinguished within 30 feet of you as the shadow lashes out at the flame.

I also know that breath weapons are considered nonmagical.

**What happens when a dragon breathes fire on a creature wielding this special shield?**

1. The breath gets extinguished (and thus doesn't affect the Aegis-wielding creature)
2. The breath weapon works as normal, since it doesn't really emit "flames" in game terms (and thus the Aegis-wielding creature is forced to make the Dexterity saving throw as normal)

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't be allowed to. Through googling "Aegis of the Raven Queen", I found it listed in [this log](https://www.adventurersleaguelog.com/users/2777/characters/6088/magic_items) as being from ["CCC-BWM-03 A Tale of Two Towers"](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/253558/CCC--BWM--003-A-Tale-of-Two-Towers). The item and its description are shown in the full-size preview.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## The dragon's breath is extinguished

#### A fire-breathing dragon breathes actual fire

If you look at red dragons' breath weapon ability - for instance, a [red dragon wyrmling](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/red-dragon-wyrmling)'s Fire Breath action - it says:

> The dragon exhales **fire** in a 15-foot cone.

Fire and flame are synonymous, thus if you had some sort of effect that continuously extinguished flame, a dragon's fire breath would also be extinguished.

#### A dragon's breath is nonmagical

According to the [Sage Advice Compendium](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf), which has this to say under "Is the breath weapon of a dragon magical?":

> Determining whether a game feature is magical is straightforward. Ask yourself these questions about the feature:
>
> - Is it a magic item?
> - Is it a spell? Or does it let you create the eﬀects of a spell
>   that’s mentioned in its description?
> - Is it a spell attack?
> - Is it fueled by the use of spell slots?
> - Does its description say it’s magical?
>
> If your answer to any of those questions is yes, the feature is magical.

Since a dragon's breath weapon meets none of the guidelines, it is not magical.

**Thus, since the breath weapon creates a nonmagical flame, there is no reason why this item would not extinguish it.**

Comment: That is definitely pleasing to read. I don't think it will come up in actual play (fire-breathing dragons are rather scarce to encounter, I think), but nice nonetheless.

Comment: @GaelL dragonborn can breathe fire too, along with hell hound and other creatures.